# SQL Server CONTAINSTABLE working well but failing on a table

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-search, containstable

I am having problems with Fulltext search on SQL Server 2008 R2. Basically I use `CONTAINSTABLE` and all works well with my tables but for some reason fails to return rows on one of the tables I am searching in.

I tried recreating the catalog and even recreating the table but no luck. Could this be a corrupt catalog or database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recreating the database from scratch through scripts sorted this out. The database must have been corrupt.